# is there a method to groupby in dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

i have a dataframe like :

```
uci_class   doc_id  sentence_id     token                      
    1         1        1      Emmanuel Macron
    1         1        1          est              
    1         1        2      president             
    1         1        2          de                 
    1         1        1      Emmanuel Macron   
    1         1        2          aussi                 
    1         1        2          president
```

i want to have in output:

```
uci_class   doc_id  sentence_id    count           
    1         1        1             2             
    1         1        2             2                           
    1         2        1             1  
    1         2        2             2
```

for example for the first row we have count=2 because if we do a group by (uci_class    doc_id  sentence_id) we will have two rows with (uci_class=1 , doc_id=1 and    sentence_id=1)

that i want to do , i want to do a group by

Comment: There are only two groups for (uci_class, doc_id, sentence_id) namely, (1, 1,1) with 3 rows and (1, 1, 2) with 4 rows.

Answer (score 2):

sure, just use the .groupby method which is documented [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html).

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
        'uci_class': ['1','1','1','1','1','1','1'],
        'doc_id': ['1','1','1','1','1','1','1'],
        'sentence_id': ['1','1','2','2','1','2','2'],
        'token': ['Emmanuel Macron', 'est', 'president', 'de', 'Emmanuel Macron','aussi','president']
})

df_grouped = df.groupby(['uci_class','doc_id','sentence_id']).count().reset_index()
print(df_grouped)
```

As an aside, I see that you are working with natural language processing. I recommend using a library that handles "tokenization" or word-based analysis a bit more gracefully that pandas will for you. Check out [nltk](https://www.nltk.org/), if you haven't already. To spill the beans, my first-ever experience with python was teaching myself how to use nltk for a project I had in college. Good luck on your work!